# How to redirect 404 error using a 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a site submitted to google webmaster tools that I helped a family member redevelop. The site is great and working but google says 4 old url's displayed crawl errors and return 404 errors.

From what i've read this is common when using CMS systems and page alias's get changed. However, while I have access to the php and .htaccess files and I can see that mod rewrite is on I don't know how to implement a 301 redirect. I'm not familiar with php code.

The 4 url's google says are errors I can't even find, so I don't know where they are being linked from. For example this is one of the errors:

mywebsite.co.uk/index.php?page=kitchens  (which produces a 404 error page)

should link, or redirect to,

```
mywebsite.co.uk/kitchens-northampton/
```

I noticed this code in the htaccess file if it's of any relevance:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

I just don't know what it means. Can anyone offer some advice?
Thank you.

Comment: This has to be handled by your CMS. Basically, your `htaccess` is redirecting every request (including a potential `404`) to the CMS's `index.php`. It's the CMS which is then throwing the `404` because no kitchen `page` is configured.

Comment: Can this be fixed within cms or in the htaccess file? The site is made with cms made simple. Each page does have its own url with the 'pretty url's' enabled if thats an issue.